# Building hector_quadrotor failed

Tags: gazebo, rosmake, hector-quadrotor

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have installed ROS and Gazebo and I tried to build this project:

> http://www.ros.org/wiki/hector_quadrotor/Tutorials/Quadrotor%20indoor%20SLAM%20demo

After I executing

> rosmake hector_quadrotor_demo

All things work well unless I meet these errors:

> ......
>
> {-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> mkdir -p bin
>
> cd build && cmake -Wdev
> -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/opt/ros/groovy/share/ros/core/rosbuild/rostoolchain.cmake
> ..
>
> -- The C compiler identification is
> GNU
>
> -- The CXX compiler identification
> is GNU
>
> -- Check for working C compiler:
> /usr/bin/gcc
>
> -- Check for working C compiler:
> /usr/bin/gcc -- works
>
> -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
>
> -- Detecting C compiler ABI info -
> done
>
> -- Check for working CXX compiler:
> /usr/bin/c++
>
> -- Check for working CXX compiler:
> /usr/bin/c++ -- works
>
> -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
>
> -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info -
> done
>
> -- Found PythonInterp:
> /usr/bin/python (found version
> "2.7.3")
>
> [rosbuild] Building package
> hector_quadrotor_gazebo_plugins
>
> Failed to invoke
> /opt/ros/groovy/bin/rospack
> deps-manifests
> hector_quadrotor_gazebo_plugins
>
> [rospack] Error: package/stack
> 'hector_quadrotor_gazebo_plugins'
> depends on non-existent package
> 'hector_gazebo_plugins' and rosdep
> claims that it is not a system
> dependency. Check the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
> or try calling 'rosdep update'
>
> CMake Error at
> /opt/ros/groovy/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:129
> (message):
>
> ```
> Failed to invoke rospack to get compile flags for package
>
> 'hector_quadrotor_gazebo_plugins'.  Look above for errors from rospack
>
> itself.  Aborting.  Please fix the broken dependency!
> ```
>
> Call Stack (most recent call first):
>
> ```
> /opt/ros/groovy/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:203
> ```
>
> (rosbuild_invoke_rospack)
>
> ```
> CMakeLists.txt:12 (rosbuild_init)
> ```
>
> -- Configuring incomplete, errors
> occurred!
>
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
>
> [ rosmake ] Output from build of
> package
> hector_quadrotor_gazebo_plugins
> written to:
>
> [ rosmake ]
> /home/hongbo-miao/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130203-101443/hector_quadrotor_gazebo_plugins/build_output.log
>
> [rosmake-1] Finished <<<
> hector_quadrotor_gazebo_plugins [FAIL]
> [ 2.95 seconds ]
>
> [ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in
> package
> hector_quadrotor_gazebo_plugins.
>
> [ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads
> to complete.
>
> [rosmake-0] Finished <<<
> hector_uav_msgs [PASS] [ 112.02
> seconds ]
>
> [ rosmake ] Results:
>
> [ rosmake ] Built 69 packages with 1
> failures.
>
> [ rosmake ] Summary output to
> directory
>
> [ rosmake ]
> /home/hongbo-miao/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130203-101443

If I continue executing

> roslaunch hector_quadrotor_demo
> indoor_slam_gazebo.launch

I will get this error:

> cannot locate
> [indoor_slam_gazebo.launch] in package
> [hector_quadrotor_demo]

Any idea? Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54111/building-hector_quadrotor-failed/) by [Hongbo Miao](https://answers.ros.org/users/4114/hongbo-miao/) on ROS Answers with karma: 70 on 2013-02-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems that you only installed the hector_quadrotor stack without its dependencies. For compiling the hector_quadrotor stack, you need at least [hector_gazebo](http://ros.org/wiki/hector_gazebo), [hector_models](http://ros.org/wiki/hector_models) and [hector_common](http://ros.org/wiki/hector_common) (if you want to publish tf). Make sure to have them in your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH or, for fuerte, install them as Ubuntu package with the `sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-hector-quadrotor` command. We are going to release hector_quadrotor for groovy soon.

The [hector_quadrotor_demo](http://ros.org/wiki/hector_quadrotor_demo) package has been moved to a separate stack, namely [hector_quadrotor_apps](http://ros.org/wiki/hector_quadrotor_apps) some time ago. For running the demos with SLAM, you will also need the [hector_slam](http://ros.org/wiki/hector_slam) package.

Information about required stacks was indeed incomplete in the tutorials. I have added the missing stacks in the prerequisites section. Thanks for reporting!

*Note to me:* Probably it would be best to provide a [rosinstall](http://ros.org/wiki/rosinstall) file containing all stacks required to run the demo, so that you can checkout them with a single command.

---

Originally posted by [Johannes Meyer](https://answers.ros.org/users/1634/johannes-meyer/) with karma: 1266 on 2013-02-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2